# From file import function (django)

Tags: python, django, function, cmd, import

I'm learning django and following a tutorial, the thing is that when I try to import a function in the file `urls.py` from `views.py` and when I run the server the cmd throws the error `no module named "views"`, and the guy in the tutorial doesn´t get that error and doesn´t talk anything about it.
(They´re in the same directory, I tried importing the function to the module `__init__`, but throws the exact same error

Comment: Hi there new contributor, make sure to be more specific on your question and provide the codes you're actually encountering problems with. There is a high possibility that you're doing something different than the tutorial of "that guy".

Comment: Check if the path is correct

Comment: Can you add `urls.py` content and `views.py` content? You can use relative import such as `from .views import ` and the name of class or function you want to import.

Answer (score 0):

in your urls.py

```
from YourApps import views
```

or

```
from .views import def_Viwe or Class_View ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u added ur application to INSTALLED_APPS?